# Страницы инфоблоков в 1С Битрикс можно выводить только в подпапках url или нет?

Tags: php, битрикс

Например, вот такое url формируется у целевой страницы элемента инфоблока `site.loc/infoblock/article`. Можно ли как-то выводить целевую страницу элемента инфоблока вот так `site.loc/article`?

Comment: Пожалуйста если вам дан ответ решивший проблему, отметьте его как верный (галочка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Да можно, для этого в настройках инфоблока в поле "URL страницы информационного блока" пропишите нужный Вам адрес.
И на будущее прежде чем задавать подобные вопросы не поленитесь заглянуть в официальную [документацию](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/user_help/) и [курсы](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/index.php), например, вот ответ на Ваш вопрос в [курсе](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=35&LESSON_ID=2011&LESSON_PATH=3906.4485.4534.2011) и [документации](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/user_help/content/iblock/iblock_edit.php) - эти материалы не просто так пишутся.